# How to parse HTML with jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have one question. I want to know how to solve the following example:

I have html site like this:

```
<div>
    <p><strong>Title 1</strong></p>
    <p>Content 1</p>
    <p>Content 2</p>
    <p><strong>Title 2</strong></p>
    <p>Content 1</p>
    <p>Content 2</p>
    <p>Content 3</p>
</div>
```

How to select "Content's" from "Title 2" like this:

> Content 1
>
> Content 2
>
> Content 3

Thanks for answer!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: Can you give any classes or ids to these or this is what you can have.

Comment: In php You may use SimpleXML or DOM functions. See the manual.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani This is everything what i can give or get...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to do this with javascript you can just hide all the p elements and show the ones after title 2 like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").hide();
    $("p:contains('Title 2')").nextAll().show();
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle of it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/LKSRh/

If you wanted to get the paragraphs of title 1 but before title 2 you would do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").hide();
    $("p:contains('Title 1')").nextUntil("p:contains('Title 2')").show();
});
```

Comment: How would do if i want to select only the content of Title 1?